# How to correctly create a CMFCListCtrl inside another window?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm having problems with the follow code

```
int CMyView::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CView::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    DWORD dwStyle = LVS_REPORT | LVS_SINGLESEL | LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CHILD;

    CMFCListCtrl TempCtrl;
    TempCtrl.Create(dwStyle, CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), this, IDC_FILTERLIST);
    CMFCHeaderCtrl& HeaderCtrl = TempCtrl.GetHeaderCtrl();
    if (!::IsWindow(HeaderCtrl.GetSafeHwnd()))
    {
        AfxMessageBox("Failed to create CMFCListCtrl properly!");
    }

    ....
```

The header control part of the CMFCListCtrl is not getting created/initialized correctly. Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not the entire problem, but one thing wrong is having TempCtrl as a local variable in the OnCreate function.  That means the variable will go out of scope at the end of OnCreate, which will destroy the List Ctrl.  TempCtrl needs to be a class variable.

Comment: In the real code TempCtrl is a member variable. I just wanted to provide a very simple sample to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: VS 2010 the above code compiles and executes correctly, with a suitable value substituted for IDC_FILTERLIST.  Can you provide a small, completely self-contained sample that will reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hi Mark, you are correct, I just made a standalone VC2010 app and the problem does not appear. I'm now looking for a heap/stack corruption in the main app. Thanks again for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you are creating a control inside a CView-derived class. Please note that the id must start from the value AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST. Otherwise it will fail. Just google AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST and you'll find the explanation why.

So, just replace your line with:

```
TempCtrl.Create(dwStyle, CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), this, AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST);
```

Comment: Thanks cha, unfortunately this didn't fix my particular problem, but you've given me another avenue to search.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above problem by using the WS_VISIBLE style at creation, but I still don't understand why this is so.